# Avoid query to recover `buffer-undo-list`

Tags: undo

Every time I commit via Magit before the buffer `COMMIT_EDITSMSG` is opened I get the question

`buffer-undo-list is not empty. Do you want to recover now? (yes or no)`

I'm guessing this is coming from an Emacs extension but I haven't been able to locate the source that prints this message neither in the Emacs sources nor under my ELPA root. Is this a known type of message or could it be triggered by the extensions https://gitlab.com/ideasman42/emacs-undo-fu and https://github.com/m2ym/undohist-el I'm using?

Comment: Please provide a link to the `persisten-undo` package you are using.

Comment: I added the links.

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that, during the query in the Minibuffer, I can check the Option "Enter debugger on Quit" and press C-g to get a stacktrace. The stacktrace is indeed triggered by my Emacs package `undohist`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (quit)
yes-or-no-p("buffer-undo-list is not empty. Do you want to recover now? ")
undohist-recover-1()
undohist-recover-safe()
run-hooks(find-file-hook)
after-find-file(nil t)
```

The reason why I didn't find this is because my `~/.emacs.d/elpa` directory is ignored by Git.